# Java Hashtable with AndEngine

Tags: java, android, andengine

I've been doing some android programming with AndEngine and came across some wierdness with Hashtables.

basically if I do this:

```
        BitmapTextureAtlas m_textureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(p_baseActivity.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

    TextureRegion texture1 = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(m_textureAtlas, p_baseActivity, "Chrysanthemum.jpg", 0, 0);

    m_textureAtlas.load();

    Sprite m_sprite1 = new Sprite(0, 0, texture1, p_baseActivity.getEngine().getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    this.attachChild(m_sprite1);
```

Everything words fine. But If I do this:

```
        BitmapTextureAtlas m_textureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(p_baseActivity.getTextureManager(), 1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

    Hashtable<String, TextureRegion> test = new Hashtable<String, TextureRegion>();
    TextureRegion texture1 = test.put("1", BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(m_textureAtlas, p_baseActivity, "Chrysanthemum.jpg", 0, 0));

    m_textureAtlas.load();

    Sprite m_sprite1 = new Sprite(0, 0, texture1, p_baseActivity.getEngine().getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    this.attachChild(m_sprite1);
```

It (the image) flickers and the dimensions are all wrong. Right now I'm ok with doing the first set of code for this project, but I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong or should I just avoid the return value of put() altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Hashtable#put` returns the previous value of the specified key in this hashtable, or null if it did not have one. In your case it is null since you just created the instance.

This will work even though from the example it is not easy to understand why you need the hashtable.

```
    Hashtable<String, TextureRegion> test = new Hashtable<String, TextureRegion>();
    TextureRegion texture1 = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(m_textureAtlas, p_baseActivity, "Chrysanthemum.jpg", 0, 0);
    test.put("1",  texture1);
```